# Can indenting affect Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, syntax, indentation

Is this possible? It shouldn't be but sometimes its behavior is quite against ordinary programming sense.

Comment: AFAIK, no (unless you have a specific example showing otherwise)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Matlab isn't affected by indentation.

They do have editors that will automatically indent the code for you, but it is for readability purposes only. Keeping your code readable with [smart-indenting](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/05/11/keep-your-code-readable-with-smart-indenting/) is always a good idea not only for yourself, but for others who may have to read through your code.

Note: ***Warnings can*** occur (depending on the IDE) if the indentation isn't consistent, but even sporadic indentation won't affect how your code executes in Matlab.

Answer (score 4):

It'll give you warnings if you don't indent properly. If you make a if or for loop or something like that and the end block isn't inline with it you'll get a possible warning that says the statement might not be aligned with its end block. CRTL+A CTRL+I is easy enough though.

Comment: To be clear: the MATLAB language will not warn you about poor indentation; the code analyzer tools in the MATLAB editor may warn you however.

Comment: The only thing I know is that I get warnings if my end blocks don't match their if/while/for blocks. A warning is a warning. I never said it would affect compiling, I just said it could pop up warnings, which is what he asked. Everyone else said it wouldn't and I gave a case of when it would. I get it in MatLab so if MatLab doesn't give it but some analyzer does, it makes no difference to me, a warning is a warning.

Comment: @Lucas: Technically, he asked if indentation could affect the code. Warnings don't affect the code, warnings affect the user. They don't affect how the code executes.

Comment: Warnings can become errors or lead to bugs that could be hard to trace. Warnings are there for a reason. MatLab changes versions twice a year, and right now our code is getting deprecation warnings. They don't affect my program at all but in the next version my code couldn't compile. In the 2012b release that indentation warning could turn into an error.

Comment: @Lucas: We're not talking about any type of warning though. We're talking about indentation warnings, which will never become errors, which will never lead to bugs. Indentation warnings are there to tell you your code is unreadable. And no, I seriously doubt Matlab will release a new version that suddenly changes indentation warnings to errors, since they don't and haven't cared about indentation before.